If, Then, ElseIf statement solves (using solver) for two of my criteria and returns, but will not solve for the third. No error messages either
I am trying to use VBA to solve for a variable to get three different returns: 10%, 16%, Breakeven. I have to use solver to avoid circular references, but I have 5 different scenarios to solve for all three criteria on. So, I thought automating the solver process would speed things up tremendously.
This is my code:
Sub EntSolver()
    
    If Range("B8").Value = "0.16" Then
        Solverok SetCell:="E44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".16", ByChange:="E9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "0.10" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="E44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".1", ByChange:="E9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "Net Income B/E" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="E45", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="E9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    End If
        
    'find a solution by solving the problem
        
    If Range("B8").Value = "0.16" Then
        Solverok SetCell:="I44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".16", ByChange:="I9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "0.10" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="I44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".10", ByChange:="I9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "Net Income B/E" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="I45", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="I9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    End If
        
    'find a solution by solving the problem
        
    If Range("B8").Value = "0.16" Then
        Solverok SetCell:="M44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".16", ByChange:="M9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "0.10" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="M44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".10", ByChange:="M9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "Net Income B/E" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="M45", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="M9"
        SolverSolve (True)
      
    End If
        
    'find a solution by solving the problem
    If Range("B8").Value = "0.16" Then
        Solverok SetCell:="Q44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".16", ByChange:="Q9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "0.10" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="Q44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".10", ByChange:="Q9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "Net Income B/E" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="Q45", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="Q9"
        SolverSolve (True)
    
    End If
        
    If Range("B8").Value = "0.16" Then
        Solverok SetCell:="U44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".16", ByChange:="U9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "0.10" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="U44", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=".10", ByChange:="U9"
        SolverSolve (True)
        
    ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "Net Income B/E" Then
        
        Solverok SetCell:="U45", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="U9"
        SolverSolve (True)
    
    End If
        
        'find a solution by solving the problem
End Sub

Cell B8 is a data validation dropdown menu that has the 10, 16, and Breakeven % options. The user should be able to choose the return, then run the code.
It works for the 16% and Breakeven options, but for some reason, it will not work for the 10% option.
I manually used solver to find the 10% variable, and it works, so I have no clue why it won't work. Please help if you have any idea about what is going on.

Have you debugged to ensure the code under ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "0.10" Then actually gets executed?

I’m not sure what you mean by debugged; I’m not familiar with vba language. Could you explain? Thanks for helping me out!

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Hard to say what the exact problem is but here are some suggested changes, and a way to reduce your code size (fewer lines means fewer bugs and easier to make changes...)
Sub EntSolver()
    
    Dim sel, ws As Worksheet, col, targ As Double, rw As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    
    sel = ws.Range("B8").Value
    
    Select Case sel    'what value to aim for, and which row to change?
        Case 0.16
            targ = 0.16
            rw = 44
        Case 0.1
            targ = 0.1
            rw = 44
        Case "Net Income B/E"
            targ = 0#
            rw = 45
        Case Else
            MsgBox "'" & sel & "' is not a valid value", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    'loop over the different columns to be solved and run Solver
    For Each col In Array("E", "I", "M", "Q", "U")
        SolverReset
        Solverok SetCell:=ws.Cells(rw, col), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=targ, ByChange:=ws.Cells(9, col)
        SolverSolve (True)
    Next col
    
End Sub


Thank you so much! I will run this code and let you know. I had a feeling my code was too long, so hopefully it was just a break in the code

I tried to run this code, and it gives me an error saying " '0.1' is not a valid value."

See edits above
